# xdmp:transaction-locks() causing timeout in cluster when transaction has no locks

Tags: marklogic

ML Server Version: 10.0-9.5

I am using [xdmp:transaction-locks](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:transaction-locks) to be able count and view the locks that a transaction has. This function is running differently in our clustered environments (more than 1 node) than it does locally (1 node). If a transaction does not have any locks and you run the function on a cluster, the request will timeout and return a [XDMP-XDQPNOSESSION](https://docs.marklogic.com/11.0/messages/XDMP-en/XDMP-XDQPNOSESSION) error. However, running the same code locally will return almost instantly and without error. If the transaction has a lock then the function returns successfully in the cluster. Below are the code samples to try to reproduce. Has anyone seen this before? Am I missing something?

Code with no locks (producing error):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

(: Gets the locks for your current host and this transaction. This should return nothing as we have no locking code here... 
    
   Locally it returns the following:
   <transaction-locks xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/host"></transaction-locks>
   
   Cluster:
   Causes timeout and returns XDMP-XDQPNOSESSION error
:)
xdmp:transaction-locks(xdmp:host(), xdmp:transaction())
```

Code with a lock:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

(: Transaction with lock. Returns successfully locally and in a cluster.

   Returns:
   <transaction-locks xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/host">
     <write>foo.xml</write>
   </transaction-locks>
:)
let $_ := xdmp:lock-for-update("foo.xml")
return xdmp:transaction-locks(xdmp:host(), xdmp:transaction())
```

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior. Seems like you would expect it to instead return quickly with an empty `<transaction-locks xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/host"/>`

Comment: @MadsHansen Yep, as a work around I have adjusted the code to only run `xdmp:transaction-locks` if the transaction is an  `update` transaction which seems to resolve the issue. Still seems like a bug with the function.

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed with MarkLogic engineering that this is not intended behavior. I have filed a bug for it, but for now you will have to work around it and try to avoid calling the function in a cluster when there are no locks.